# Docker Resource wordnet not found

Tags: python, docker, nltk, wordnet

I am building a docker container using the following Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /app


COPY . /app


# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1


# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


Run apt update -y
Run apt install python3 python3-pip -y
# Install pip requirements


COPY ./tokenize /root/nltk_data/tokenize
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Run pip3 install gunicorn
Run pip3 install pip tensorflow==2.3.0




EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "run:app"]
```

i am getting this err :

```
**********************************************************************
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')

  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/wordnet

  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

Comment: It seems whatever you copy to `/root/ntlk_data` into the image is not enough. Have you verified that everything needed really is there?

Answer (score 0):

The error states when `ganicorn` try to start serving your program, the program seeks for Wordnet resource related to `nltk`. A simple solution to this, is to download the resource beforehand. to do so you can create a new file that contains commands named `RUN.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash    
python -c "import nltk\nnltk.download('wordnet')"
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run:app
```

Copy the new file in your image then use this `.sh` file to fire up your server!

```
CMD /the/new/file/location/RUN.sh
```